# Angular 2 subject next not working

Tags: angular, observable, subject

I have a service with a method that checks if the logged in user has X roles passed by parameter. The question is that only the next function works if I put it in a "setTimeout" otherwise the subscribers receive nothing.

```
checkRoles(roles:Array<string>):Observable<boolean>{
        let sub = new Subject<boolean>();
        this.loggedUser$.subscribe(user=>{
            if(!isUndefined(user.roles)){
                user.roles.forEach(userRole => {
                    if(roles.indexOf(userRole.name) !==-1){
                        //Todo buscar porque en stackoverflow
                        setTimeout(()=>sub.next(true),1);
                    }
                });
                setTimeout(()=>sub.next(false),1);
            }
        });

        return sub.asObservable().first();
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to use AsyncSubject instead of Subject?

Comment: I think your problem is because when you use Subject, you must be subscribed before you try to send data with .next() method. Try it with AsyncSubject

Comment: It does not work